# deploying only modified reports from sandbox to production via vscode

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, vs-code, devopscenter

my use case : fix reports in bulk when there is a change, such as a replacement on opportunity stage.

note: we do not use source tracking - we use sandboxes for development.

first, i download all reports using the salesforce package generator extension in vscode.

then i run `force:source:tracking:reset` because i do not want to push all reports, just the modified ones

then i do find/replace in the reports folder to make the changes

and then i do `force:source:push` and only the modified reports are pushed to the sandbox.

now i want to push only the modified reports to production - not all the thousands of reports in the reports folder.

I have been able to do this using devops center. I use `sfdx force:source:push` to a source tracked sandbox, and then deployed to prod via devops center, but i would prefer to do it all via sfdx, but cant figure out how to just include the modified reports.

I tried using sfdx force:source:convert to create a package, but it contained all reports, not just the ones I modified.

I suppose I could do some command line kung fu to generate a list of modified files, but feels like I'm missing something obvious.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [sfdx-git-delta](https://github.com/scolladon/sfdx-git-delta) , that can generate a package.xml from the diff between 2 commits, that will contain only the metadatas that has been created or updated since the previous commit

If you want an easier way to use it, the command is available in [VsCode SFDX Hardis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis) like in screenshot below

[image]

After running sfdx-git-delta , you can manually update the package.xml to keep only the block with `<name>Report</name>` , then call `sfdx force:source:deploy -x yourpackage.xml -u yourproductionorguser`

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Glad to know I'm not missing anything obvious.  May explore a script to delete files based on last modified date, as we are just using vscode and sandbox, and are not using source control/git.  I will update the title  to reflect this.

Comment: You really should use git :) if you need to know how, you can read this article:) https://salesforcedevops.net/index.php/2023/03/01/sfdx-hardis-open-source-salesforce-release-management/